# MP3 tags Cyrillic chars

Tags: character-encoding, tagging, audacious

I have some `mp3` files with Cyrillic chars on file names and also on their tags.

I'm using `audacious` to play them. See the file info below:

[image]

Is it possible to change some encoding to show the contents correctly?

**Âûñîêî** should be **Высоко**, I guess.

Comment: Are thes ID3v1 or ID3v2 tags? If these are v1 then there is no encoding information available and you can only guess.

Comment: @Anthon, I don't know. How to discover the version?

Comment: Some commandline tools will tell you. e.g. [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/). It can do some tricks with encoding, but I am not sure if it can do cyrillic ID3v1 to UTF-8 ID3v2, I think not because there seems no way to specify the input encoding.

Comment: Can you share one of these files, or are they copyrighted?

Comment: I installed `eyed3` and the output is ID3 v2.3.

Comment: Then either audacious does not support the encoding, or it is not there. If your filenames are correct and regular (e.g. nr. artist - song_title ) you could try and set the name and artist with eyeD3 from the filename after splitting that. Do one file first by hand and see if Audacious displays stuff after that correctly.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is with audacious since the output of `eyed3` also have problems to show the chars. From `man eyed3` I got *Note  that, unfortunately, utf8 is not supported by ID3 v2.3 tags*. So I guess that I'm still in trouble. I'll try to retag.

Comment: I was right. Trying to pass the author's name using Ю for example, I got an error. UTF8 is not supported.

Comment: I should have thought about asking if eyeD3 displayed correctly. eyeD3 supports writing id3V2 2.4 so you could try my previous suggesting.

Comment: What's strange is that your Localização section displays them correctly so it must be getting the info from somewhere.

Comment: @terdon I think that is the filename, hence my suggestion to update the tags from the filename parts.

Comment: The file name is correctly (`pcmanfm` exhibit it right). I tried to pass a Cyrillic char using `eyeD3 -a "Ю"` and I got *Uncaught exception: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(256)*. Maybe I should install the newest version from the source since the repository one is `eyeD3 0.6.17`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any Cyrillic characters in my music collection but I can do Greek with no problem using the latest version of `eyed3` installed by `sudo pip install --upgrade eyed3`:

```
 $ eyeD3 Μπεστ\ οφ/Τζίμης\ Πανούσης\ -\ Κάγκελα\ Παντού.mp3 
Τζίμης Πανούσης - Κάγκελα Παντού.mp3    [ 3.43 MB ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 03:45 MPEG1, Layer III    [ 128 kb/s @ 44100 Hz - Joint stereo ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID3 v2.4:
title: Tzimis Panousis-Kagkela Pantou.mp3
artist: Tzimis Panousis
album: Unknown
```

In the example above, I have a directory (album name) called `Μπεστ οφ`  which contains a song called `Κάγκελα Παντού` by `Τζίμης Πανούσης`. As you can see in the `id3tool` output above, the tags are not in Greek. Let's fix that:

```
$ eyeD3 -A "Μπεστ οφ" \
        -t "Κάγκελα Παντού" \
        -a "Τζίμης Πανούσης" \
        "./Μπεστ οφ/Τζίμης Πανούσης - Κάγκελα Παντού.mp3"
```

That correctly set the tags using the Greek alphabet:

```
$ eyeD3 Μπεστ\ οφ/Τζίμης\ Πανούσης\ -\ Κάγκελα\ Παντού.mp3 
Τζίμης Πανούσης - Κάγκελα Παντού.mp3    [ 3.43 MB ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 03:45 MPEG1, Layer III    [ 128 kb/s @ 44100 Hz - Joint stereo ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID3 v2.4:
title: Κάγκελα Παντού
artist: Τζίμης Πανούσης
album: Μπεστ οφ
```

OK, but since the information is encoded in the name of the file, this can be automated. In the example above, the file name has this format:

```
Album/Artist - Title.mp3
```

So, we can parse and add the tags for all files with a little [shell magic](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
find . -type f -name "*mp3" | while read file; do 
    album="$(basename "$(dirname "$file")")"; 
    filename="$(basename "$file")"; 
    artist=${filename%%-*}; 
    title=${filename##*-}; 
    title=${title%%.mp3}; 
    eyeD3 -A "$album" -t "$title" -a "$artist" "$file"; 
done
```

After running this command, all files will have had their id3 tags modified:

[image]

Comment: Please note that as Sigur commented, it might be that older versions of eyeD3 do not work correctly. I would also explicitly set `--to-v2.4` to be sure the tag version is updated.

Comment: The script worked so nice! You can see here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42709342/03.png
Thanks so much.

Comment: @terdon, OK. Now I have to adapt the script. Since my file name is `Юлия Савичева - 03 - Отпусти меня.mp3` the title tag is starting with empty space. I don't know why. Maybe because the number. Also the track number does not appear. I don't care but since it is contained in file name I guess that it should be used somewhere in the tag.

Comment: @Sigur this is just an example, I recommend you post a new question explaining the format of your file names and I'll give you a more specific script.

Comment: @terdon, done! http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114413/19195

Comment: @Mikel I rolled back your edit because that will fail if there is no space.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can use the `mid3iconv` utility from the [python-mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package:

```
$ mid3iconv
Usage: mid3iconv [OPTION] [FILE]...

Mutagen-based replacement the id3iconv utility, which converts ID3 tags from
legacy encodings to Unicode and stores them using the ID3v2 format.

Options:
...
  -e ENCODING, --encoding=ENCODING
...
  --force-v1            Use an ID3v1 tag even if an ID3v2 tag is present
  --remove-v1           Remove v1 tag after processing the files
```

So, basically, running

```
mid3iconv -eCP1251 --remove-v1
```

will yield exactly the result you're looking for.

Comment: You may want also to `--dry-run` and display its result with `--debug`. And `for f in **/*.mp3; do mid3conv --debug -eXXX $f; done` after you make sure that all subdirectories are encoded in the same way.

Comment: Or with `find`: `find . -name '*.mp3' | while read path; do mid3iconv -eCP1251 --remove-v1 "$path"; done`

Answer (score 3):

I could succesfully update an MP3 file using:

```
eyeD3 -a "Ю" abc.mp3
```

This was done with eyeD3 0.7.4-beta as installed using `pip` from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi):

```
pip install eyeD3
```

Using that eyeD3 you could use a script to extract the artist and title from the MP3's file path and set them as ID3v2 2.4 tags with eyeD3.

Comment: Can you confirm that the info is displayed correctly in `audacious` or `vlc` or any other GUI app? Following the procedure in my answer it works fine on the CLI but GUI apps seem to ignore it and take the info from somewhere else.

Comment: I installed *eyeD3 0.7.4-beta (C) Copyright 2002-2013 Travis Shirk* from the source. I rename my file to `abc.mp3` (to remove all Cyrillic chars from file name) but `eyeD3 -a "Ю" abc.mp3` produces errors. After some info I can find *Writing ID3 version v2.3 Uncaught exception: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(256)*.

Comment: @terdon vlc, audacious both display fine. You might need to specify --to-v2.4 if you start with a v2.3 file to begin with.

Comment: It worked! `eyeD3 --encoding utf8 -a "Ю" abc.mp3` had success!

Comment: Thanks, Anthon, I think id3tool only works with v1. @Sigur I've changed my answer to use eyeD3 as suggested by Anthon.

Comment: @terdon, nice! Now I'll try to use your script to update the tags. But in my case I need to pass the encoding option. Thanks.

Comment: @terdon that looks good +1-ed it, I was to laz^H^H^Hbusy doing the pathname splitting and would probably have done that kind of stuff in Python and use [mutagen](https://code.google.com/p/mutagen/) without external programs for setting the tags, like I did for my daughter's automatic mp4 -> mp3 conversion.

Comment: @Anthon mutagen looks good, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @terdon It is good, but AFAIK it only supports ID3v2 2.4 tagging not 2.3. If you use the files with Windows software as well that might be a problem, IIRC 10+ years after the 2.4 standard Microsoft still did not support it in their software.