# Script to split string

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

[@terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114396/19195) provides this script:

```
find . -type f -name "*mp3" | while read file; do 
    album="$(basename "$(dirname "$file")")"; 
    filename="$(basename "$file")"; 
    artist=${filename%%-*}; 
    title=${filename##*-}; 
    title=${title%%.mp3}; 
    eyeD3 -A "$album" -t "$title" -a "$artist" "$file"; 
done
```

It makes use of `eyeD3` to update mp3 tags. It extracts Album, Artist and Title from file name, supposing that the file name is `Album/Artist - Title.mp3`.

Well, after running it the Title field is starting with a blank space. See below:

[image]

How to fix this if my mp3 files have the pattern

```
Album/<Artist with possible spaces> - <track number> - <Title with possible spaces>.mp3
```

Comment: This might not be in the domain of bash scripting anymore. Using python instead might be beneficial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MP3 tags Cyrillic chars](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114382/mp3-tags-cyrillic-chars)

Comment: @Sigur I don't understand why you didn't just update your question and comment there.

Comment: It was suggested to me to ask as a new question since the problem now is related with script and strings manipulation. Not necessarily tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I assume that your names do not *always* have these spaces, the easiest thing to do would be to simply remove the space if present:

```
find . -type f -name "*mp3" | 
  while read file; do 
   album="$(basename "$(dirname "$file")")"; 
   filename="$(basename "$file")"; 
   artist=${filename%%-*}; artist=${artist%% }; artist=${artist## };
   title=${filename##*-}; title=${title%% }; title=${title## };
   title=${title%%.mp3}; 
   eyeD3 -A "$album" -t "$title" -a "$artist" "$file";
 done
```

Comment: Perfect. Now everything is fine. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Ksh extended glob patterns give [wildcards](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) the power of regular expressions. In bash, turn them on with `shopt -s extglob`.

Then, instead of

```
title=${filename##*-}
```

to remove the part of `$filename` up to the last `-`, you can use

```
title=${filename##*- #}
```

to also strip whitespace after the `-`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the leading space for the Artist, you could use sed. Something like this should work.

```
artist=${filename%%-*}; 
artist=`echo $artist |  sed 's/^ *//g'`;
```